# Get Collection Name with Like Command in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, collections

Is it possible to use Like command for getCollectionNames in Mongodb?

Something like that:
db.getCollectionNames({"/*dummy*/"})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`db.getCollectionNames()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.getCollectionNames/) with [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
db.getCollectionNames().filter(function (collection) { return /dummy/.test(collection) })
```